# PMD Eclipse Plugin error: An internal error occurred during: "ReviewCode"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pmd

I need your help to solve my problem:

I'm modifying the Eclipse PMD Plugin for introduce my own rulesets in the plugin, and when I have installed my modified plugin, the IDE starts OK, but when I test it in any Java project to check the PMD with the option "Check Code with PMD", Eclipse shows me this error message:

*An internal error occurred during: "ReviewCode". tried to access field net.sourceforge.pmd.CommonAbstractRule.properties from class com.mypackage.cal.cca.crregvalijav.uti.ClassASL2*

The PMD plugin configuration, libraries, manifest file, etc, seems to be the same as the previous plugin version that worked. The rulesets and the xml files for the rule definitions that I have implemented are like the previous version of the plugin that worked for me.

That previous version worked in Juno and in Kepler, but the actual one modified by me doesn´t work in any IDE.

Can anybody help me and explain me why I have this error in my PMD plugin when I check its behavior??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory (or in the Error Log) to see if there is a more detailed message.

Comment: Hi Greg449, I have taken a look into the log file of the .metadata directory, and it looks like this problem takes place when PMD analyze the rules with properties defined. So when PMD analyze a rule with any <property>...</property> defined, it doesn't find the property in xml file of the rule. It shows in the .log file this error:  !ENTRY net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.plugin 1 0 2014-09-17 14:07:11.714
!MESSAGE Review code command terminated. 0 rules were executed against 0 files. PMD was not executed.