# An internal error occurred during: "ReviewCode". beans/Registration : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pmd

I am working on a Java Web Application in Eclipse. When checking my code with PMD, I get the following error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "ReviewCode".
com/infy/jcart/beans/Registration : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

I have checked certain links on StackOverflow which talk about this error:

[Peculiar Eclipse java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError, Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624038/peculiar-eclipse-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor)

[PMD Eclipse Plugin error: An internal error occurred during: "ReviewCode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25890344/pmd-eclipse-plugin-error-an-internal-error-occurred-during-reviewcode)

So, I have come to know that this error happens because of some incompatible JRE/JDK versions. I have set the compiler version to 1.8 properly and added JRE 1.8 in Build Path also. But still the error persists while checking PMD.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that the JRE you are using to run Eclipse is *not* 1.8, but that the PMD version you are running has been compiled using 1.8.  Check the JAVA_HOME variable and make sure it points to a 1.8 JRE.

Also, you can go to Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Configuration.

You should have a line like this:

-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib

(I'm on a mac, yours will point to a windows path if you are on windows.) Make sure that this is pointing to a 1.8 JRE as well.

Comment: I found out that we should give -vm comments to make it point to the specific jre as you mentioned in your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410511/eclipse-jvm-configuration. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes - major.minor version 52.0 is Java 8 (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file).

The class com.infy.jcart.beans.Registration seems to have been compiled with java8 - as you described.

Then it depends on which version of PMD/PMD-Eclipse-Plugin you are using. PMD supports java8 beginning with version 5.1.2 (initial support was with 5.1.0, but class file loading only works with 5.1.2) - and PMD Eclipse Plugin 4.0.4.v20140909-1748.

I'd suggest to try updating the PMD Eclipse Plugin to the latest version available from the update site https://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/ .

Comment: Thanks for interest in my question. But I think the PMD plug-in is the latest version. Since I already updated that. Problem was the jre version of Eclipse which I changed in eclipse.ini file. It worked fine after that.